# Understanding Xcode build time summary

Tags: xcode

I am trying to generate the Xcode build summary for my project so that I can optimize the bottlenecks. As per attached screenshot

[image: Built Time Summary]

Total build time it shows at the bottom is 135.3 seconds. While the first module CompileC takes 449.356 seconds. I know Xcode do some parallelization while building the project but I am not sure how it is calculating this summary time. Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this is old, but I was looking into this, and I came across this comment by Rick Ballard, an Apple Xcode build system engineer.

> Yes – many commands, especially compilation, are able to run in parallel with each other, so multicore machines will indeed finish the build much faster than the time it took to run each of the commands.

In other words, the quoted numbers are core-seconds, not real time, except for the last one. So if you have six cores, your CompileC task might only take 449/6 = 75 seconds. You've got, maybe, 660 core-seconds, so you'd get about 110 clock-seconds, which looks about right versus 135 total time.

Comment: In my case i have 4 cores, So ideally it should be around 166 total time. But i believe the explanation you provided makes sense. Thanks for reading it out & responding.